# Where is the search bar that can search a specific pixel by entering the coordinates of that pixel in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

Searching the pixel immediately by entering coordinates(x,y) to the search bar.
Where is the search bar?

I mean there are too many pixels in an image. If we search the specific pixel one by one by ourselves, it is inefficient. Maybe there is a search bar that will point to the desired pixel after we enter the coordinates of that pixel to it. Search the pixel of the coordinates.

Comment: The coordinates of the cursor/pointer are a the bottom of the image window. The only "Search" I'm aware of is that you can enter `/` followed by some text and Gimp will show you the commands/filter with said text. Maybe you should edit your question to explain your initial problem.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What do you mean by "search for a co-ordinate"?  There's no such functionality in GIMP.  What are you actually trying to achieve by doing this?  At the moment, your question reads like an [XY Problem.](https://xyproblem.info/). Can you please edit your question and provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for differences between each pixel. I need a search bar to augment efficiency.

Comment: What kind of differences between pixels? Are you talking about a difference blending mode perhaps?  You say to augment efficiency, but with what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to a pixel you move your mouse/pointer, looking at the pointer coordinates at the bottom of the window. You can of course zoom in to make it easier to hit a given pixel.

If you want to "mark the spot" there are several ways:

### Guides

- You just create two [guides](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-image-guides.html) (vertical and horizontal) that intersect on the pixel.
- You use the Measure tool. Move to the pixel, click, then depress <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click again. This creates two guides that intersect on the pixel

### Sample points

You can also create [samples points](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-sample-point-dialog.html). These are created like guides, by dragging from a ruler, but also depressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> at the same time. You can later move/delete them using the Color picker tool. When you have sample points, you can have their values permanently displayed (as RGB, HSV, LCH...) in the Sample Points dialog:

[image]

These values will even change while tools are used.